# Unable to define a mapping including the '.' key

Tags: vim, gvim

I am trying to define a mapping for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> as follows:

```
  map <C-.> :bn<CR>
```

This does not work. Typing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>.</kbd> just results in repeating the last action just as you would get when typing <kbd>.</kbd>. Note that I do not want to change the behaviour of <kbd>.</kbd>. Any idea how to get this to work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot assign a mapping to any key that does not send some kind of a different signal back from the keyboard. Since `<C-.>` doesn't send anything back, as opposed to `<.>`, you cannot use it.